# How to change result of a method in one line?

Tags: ruby

I need to change the output of a method a bit: Execute the function, and if it's a empty string, then convert it to a "1". How can i write this short on just one line?

```
var = some_really_long_method(foo)
var = "1" if var == ""
```

I tried below, but that does call the method twice, right?

```
var = some_really_long_method(foo) == "" ? "1" : some_really_long_method(foo)
```

Comment: if the method could return nil instead of "" you can do: var = some_really_long_method || "1"

Comment: I was looking for something like that. But I understand there is unfortunately not a way to do the same with a empty string? Would you please confirm?

Comment: nope, have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Object.html#method-i-then):

```
def some_really_long_method
  p 'called'
  p res = ["", "10"].sample
  res
end

var = some_really_long_method.then { |m| m == "" ? '1' : m }
```

You can check for yourself that the method is called once.

Comment: oh..always nice, a new method.

Comment: alternatively but not dissimilar enough for a new answer `var = some_really_long_method(foo).tap {|s| s.replace("1") if s.empty?}`

Answer (score 1):

Newlines are optional in Ruby, they can always be replaced with either an expression separator (`;`), a keyword (e.g. `then`, `do`), or sometimes just whitespace.

Therefore, every program, no matter how complex, can always be written in one line, just by removing the linebreaks:

```
var = some_really_long_method(foo); var = "1" if var == ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var = "1" if (var = some_really_long_method(foo)) == ""
```